# Blank screen while deploying Qt QML application to Android

Tags: android, qt, x86, qml, android-virtual-device

I have downloaded Android Studio and I am using a x86 AVD to run my application. I am able to deploy my application to the emulator but it always shows a blank white screen. This happens only if my application has some QML code, if I run a pure C++ example then the app is correctly displayed.
Code below.

```
import QtQuick 2.6
import QtQuick.Controls 1.0
ApplicationWindow{
    color: "blue"
    height: 500; width: 400
    Text {
        id: name
        text: qsTr("text")
        anchors.centerIn: parent
    }
}
```

Comment: Make your tests on a computer. When it works try on android. It's easier to learn QML on a computer.

Answer (score 4):

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-applicationwindow.html#details says:

> Note: By default, an `ApplicationWindow` is not visible.

So you have to set

```
visible: true
```

Comment: That does work partially, now I am able to see that the screen is blue like it should be, but the text still doesn't show

Comment: Try a `Rectangle`, perhaps?

Comment: Tried but doesn't work. If I insert a `MouseArea` and capture the clicked signal, it does work.

Comment: That's weird. What if you create a custom `QQuickItem` or `QQuickPaintedItem` and check that their rendering functions are called? Alternatively you could step into e.g. `QQuickRectangle::updatePaintNode()`: http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtdeclarative.git/tree/src/quick/items/qquickrectangle.cpp#n474 (if you have debug symbols for the Qt libraries)

Comment: Ok so I tried with a custom `QQuickPaintedItem` and used qDebug() to check if the [_`paint`_](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qquickpainteditem.html#paint) method was called and it is. So the rendering seems to be triggered at least.